# How can I remove content from the front page?

Tags: theming

Made page--front.tpl.php. Created the view for content-type: news for example. Then put the view block in a block region. View block - only display news type limit at 1 or 2.

But when viewing the front page, all content types' content shows up on the front page along with the view block. I checked that it was managed by Display Suite but it shouldn't show show all contents on front page.

Why does this happen?

**Update**

Uncheck "promoted to front page" checkbox on all entries and it worked.

Other question:

"No front page content has been created yet.
Add new content"

How can I remove this text above on front page? I am using blocks most of the time, so text shouldn't be there.

Comment: It sound like what @dwcdev said below. I think you have set your content type with "Promoted to front page" as default. Check your content type and remove all of them from "Promoted to front page".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have your content type to "Publish to front page".  Edit your content and un-check "Promote to front page":

[image]

Comment: yes i did uncheck the promoted to front page checkbox but still cant :(. Updated: i checked inside the entry and found that some were promoted to front. it worked by unchecking thanks

Comment: Excellent.  Please click the check mark if this answered your problem.

Comment: still missing my next qn on the "No front page content has been created yet. Add new content"

Comment: I think they want you to make a new thread for a new question.  Post another thread, and I'll answer it for you ;-)

Comment: made a thread already - http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/152432/can-no-front-page-content-has-been-created-yet-add-new-content-be-removed-tot. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to remove the feature that automatically adds all your content to the front page, you'll need to go to `Configuration -> Site Information -> Front Page` and set an individual piece of content to be displayed as your front page ie.. `node/xx`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display very specific contents on front page, then you shouldn't write

```
print render($page['content']);
```

in the front page. remove this code. If it is not there, then update your question and put the `page--front.tpl.php` code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This what I do on most of my project. I used the [Empty Front Page module](https://www.drupal.org/project/empty_front_page) and this would give me a blank front page. From here I can organize anything into blocks. If you wish to have a the latest new or blog you can created a block view and add it to the front page.