# Can "No front page content has been created yet. Add new content" be removed totally?

Tags: theming

I noticed that if there is content placed in the main content block, "No front page content has been created yet. Add new content" will appear on front page or perhaps any page. Most templates will be done in blocks, except node pages.

Can it be totally removed? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your theme's template.php file

```
function THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['is_front']) {
    unset($variables['page']['content']['system_main']);
  }
}
```

Comment: did that before but it wouldn't work. now it is working when I tried again. weird. thanks!

Comment: Template/theme changes often require a cache clear.

Answer (score 1):

Easy. Specify a front page other than the default in your site configuration settings.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you did not create an front page or home page yet.So you should create an page which will be your default home page.

So first create a page

And Go to

```
`Configuration->System->System Information`
```

and set the `url` Under `'Default front page'`

You also can create a template file for front page as `page--front.tpl.php`

For more info check [front page template](https://www.drupal.org/node/317461)
and [front page](https://www.drupal.org/node/1049290)

Comment: thanks but i have created page--front.tpl.php and it is still showing content. :( will look into the links